# Python: find on string return none

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I'm working on a project to parse HTML page. It is for an internal website within a company but I changed the example so you can try.

I get the source code of a HTML page and I search for a certain markup. Then I want to extract a substring of this markup but it doesn't work. Python returns a none... Hier below my code with in comment the return of Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.resto.be/restaurant/liege/4000-liege/8219-le-bar-a-gouts/")
page_source = response.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source)
name = soup.find_all("meta", attrs={"itemprop":"name"})
print(name[0])
# <meta content="LE BAR A GOUTS" itemprop="name"/>

print(name[0].find("<meta"))
# none
```

Comment: In Python 2, `print` is a statement, not a function. You can safely remove the `(..)` parentheses here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have a string, you have a *tag object*. Printing the tag has a nice HTML represention, but it is not a string object.

As such, you are using the BeautifulSoup `Tag.find()` function, and it returns `None` if there are no child tags with the tag name `<meta`. Which indeed there are not here.

If you wanted to find the `content` attribute, use item access:

```
print name[0]['content']
```

Comment: I didn't understand everything about tag.find but you helped me very well! Indeed with print name[0]['content'] it works! I don't really understand what is a tag in BeautifulSoup.

Comment: @DescampsAu: The `soup` object is also a tag (the top level). `find()` and `find_all()` and such can all be called on tag objects.

Comment: Or  `name[0].get('content')` in case you want to search multiple tags which may or may not have the attribute.

Comment: @DescampsAu: see [Kinds of objects](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#kinds-of-objects).